# How can I take the sum of consecutive series with True/False Values Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Data

```
A     B      Result
3   True       0
1   True       0
5   True       0
6   False      9
2   True       0 
6   True       8
```

How can I get the sum of all true values before and after the false Values
as 3 + 1 + 5 = 9 and 2 + 6 = 8

How can i do that with Pandas Python default functions

Comment: Will you always just have one `False` value or will there be an indefinite number of partitions?

Comment: not indefinite numbers but sometimes it may be 5 or 10 or less than that

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask further questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use apply `df.groupby.cumsum()` on a `pd.Series.cumsum()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 6, 1, 4],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]})
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(bool)

df['result'] = df.groupby((~df['B']).cumsum())['A'].cumsum().shift()
df.loc[df['B'] | (df.index == df.index[-1]), 'result'] = 0

#    A      B  result
# 0  3   True     0.0
# 1  1   True     0.0
# 2  5   True     0.0
# 3  6  False     9.0
# 4  2   True     0.0
# 5  6  False     8.0
# 6  1  False     6.0
# 7  4   True     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one False value in B, you can do:

```
df.loc[df.B.idxmin(),'Result'] = df.loc[:df.B.idxmin()-1].A.sum()
df.loc[df.index[-1],'Result'] = df.loc[df.B.idxmin()+1:].A.sum()
df
Out[145]: 
   A      B  Result
0  3   True       0
1  1   True       0
2  5   True       0
3  6  False       9
4  2   True       0
5  6   True       8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get sum of True values in your dataFrame. This will work when there is one or more False in your dataFrame cloumn  'B'

```
## Get the index of all False values in column B and store it in lst
lst = df[df.B=='False'].index

sum=0
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    if i == 0 :
        # Sum upto 1st False location
        sum = df.iloc[:lst[i]].A.sum()

    if i == len(lst):
        # Sum from last False location to the end of row index
        sum = df.iloc[lst[i-1]+1:].A.sum()
    elif i!=0:
        #  Sum for intermediate False locations
        sum = df.iloc[lst[i-1]+1:lst[i]].A.sum()
    print ("iteration= %d, Sum = %d" %(i, sum))
    # Clearing sum for next iteration
    sum=0
```

Output will look like

```
iteration= 0, Sum = 9
iteration= 1, Sum = 8
```

If you have multiple False in your dataFrame,

```
   A      B  Result
0  3   True       0
1  1  False       0
2  5   True       0
3  6  False       9
4  2   True       0
5  6   True       8
```

The output will look like:

```
iteration= 0, Sum = 3
iteration= 1, Sum = 5
iteration= 2, Sum = 8
```